# British science-fiction novel where aliens torture the elderly on an island resort

Tags: story-identification, novel

Been driving myself crazy trying to remember the name of this book; basically, an old man (a caretaker, I think) finds a brood of eggs on an island resort. The eggs hatch a bunch of nasty, telepathic aliens that have their fun torturing the elderly people at the resort. I remember it being British and released sometime in the 70s or 80s.

It had a transgressive bent, from what I can recall.

Some basic information:

1. It's a book.
2. The author, and all of the human characters, are British.
3. It was published sometime in the 70s or 80s; maybe the 90s.
4. The cover features a grotesque-looking alien.
5. The aliens are sadistic and torture people for sexual pleasure.
6. It's set on a tropical island; specifically, a resort.
7. I believe the title starts with "The", followed by the name of the aliens. It was some sort of nonsense-sounding word.
8. I believe it was only published as a paperback.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When did you read this?  Do you recall the cover art or any character or place names?

Comment: Ages ago. About ten years. The cover art has an alien on it that looks pretty nasty; I can't recall any of the character names, but I do remember that the title is short. Starts with "The," followed by the name of the aliens in the book.

Comment: _Cocoon_ in the Bizarro Universe

Comment: Not Cocoon, I'm afraid. It was a book.

Comment: @jstek Of course not; that was a joke.

Comment: @jstek: If a correct answer is provided, you can accept by clicking the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is the very hard to find horror novel *The Jim Jams* by Michael Green (1994).

It is exactly as described: the twisted little monsters are the Jim Jams, hatched from eggs found on an island beach. The terrorize the inhabitants - many elderly - in surreal ways.

Cover is quite memorable:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! This is the exact book!

Comment: Managed to find a copy on the world-wide web; I was wrong on several accounts. 1. Added the vague quality of "British" to it --- maybe because I associate it with being elderly. 2. It was published in the 90s.